# Dailymotion Api - can't make the "created_after" filter to work properly

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am using the dailymotion api to retrieve all user's videos created after a specific time.

```
Example Request url:
    https://api.dailymotion.com/user/x1g65ms/videos?created_after=1423578052
```

The problem is, the api is returning videos created slightly before the specified timestamp.
You can try it yourself by using the api explorer: https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools#/user/videos/list 
using these parameters as en example:

```
id=x1g65ms
fields='created_time,'
```

and with

```
created_after=1423578052 --> returns videos with created_time 1423578051
created_after=1423578059 --> returns videos with created_time 1423578051
created_after=1423578060 --> doesn't return video
```

Is there something I don't understand? Am I doing these tests right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there may be a few seconds difference, but it will always be less than a minute. Indeed, the created_* filters are rounding dates on purpose to the minute (the aim is to have better performances).
This behavior shouldn't be an issue more most of the use-cases.